# Android - как узнать создался ли элемент

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Динамический создаю кнопку, как мне узнать что кнопка создана? Точнее, мне нужно условие (пока кнопка не создана) не делать того-то?

Answer (score 1):

Button btn = new Button(this);
здесь уже кнопка создана, но пока не добавлена на экран

mainLayout.addView(btn);
далее после добавления кнопки менять значение на true, и вызивать нужный метод.

Comment: не дадите развернутый ответ , я новичок и не понимаю какое значение надо на тру менять

Answer (score 0):

Если под "создано" имеется в виду отображение на экране, тогда так:

```
button.post(new Runnable() { 
  @Override  
  public void run() { 
     // делаем что-то, когда кнопка отображена 
     } 
  } );
```